# Recursively search binary tree

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, graph, binary-search-tree

I'm supposed to search for a given album from a binary tree and return it. Here's what I have so far:

```
public AlbumNode getAlbum(AlbumNode root, String name) {
    if (root != null) {
        if(root.left != null) getAlbum(root.left, name);
        if(root.right != null) getAlbum(root.right, name);
    }
    if(root.getName().equals(name)) return root;

    return null;
}
```

I know what the problem is (I think), but I'm stuck... After getting the names of all the nodes, it compares them to name, but it does this for all of them and returns the last one checked(which is always the root of the binary tree). How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you checking name in Binary Search Tree or Binary Tree?

Comment: binary search tree, I want it to return once it finds a match.

Comment: The main problem is that you search the left tree but then throw away the answer.  Then you do the same for the right tree.  I would ask you to do some thinking about how you could actually _use_ the results of those two recursive searches, instead of throwing them away.  Unfortunately, a couple posters have done your thinking for you, so it's too late.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
public AlbumNode getAlbum(AlbumNode node, String name) {
    if (node == null) {     // this checks the base case
        return null;        // your original code failed for a null root
    } else {
        if (node.getName().equals(name)) {
            return node;
        } else {
            AlbumNode result = getAlbum(node.left, name);
            if (result != null) {
                return result;
            }
            result = getAlbum(node.right, name);

            return result;  // you need to return the result inside the recursion
        }                   // your original code never returned the recursive calls
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Now time to study this and what I did wrong. I wish I could get recursion this quickly... ._.

Comment: This is actually wrong if the comment is correct that it's a binary search tree.  But I can see that your answer came before the comment.

Answer (score 2):

The code should capture the node which has result as:

```
public AlbumNode getAlbum(AlbumNode root, String name) {
    AlbumNode result;
    if(root.getName().equals(name)){
      return root;
    }
    if (root != null) {
        if(root.left != null) result = getAlbum(root.left, name);
        if(result != null) {
            return result;
        } 
        if(root.right != null) result = getAlbum(root.right, name);
    }
    return result;
}
```

In case of a `Binary Tree` an item can be present more than once. So you may need to modify this code to capture a list of all of them.

Comment: Theres one issue with this snippet, if the search find album on the left side, result will be overwritten by the second `getAlbum` call

Comment: @Toumash I believe you commented while I was editing :)

Comment: @akhil_mittal Yes, i was, but the error is still there. Check your inner ifs to not confuse OP.. After first getAlbum() you must check if the result is null, if yes, proceed, if not null return that result `if (result != null) {  return result; }`  Code probably works, because OP has the result in the left branch. Just take a look at the accepted one - that is perfect

Comment: These kinda mistakes happen when you are feeling sleepy. By the way thanks :)